# Getting data from IMDB with json

Tags: php, json, api

I keep [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/) movies id's in my db. Is there a way to get imdb movies data by their ids?

I have a json like that

```
http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=titanic3d
```

What I want is that taking json by id ? Is there a json like that?

Comment: [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) Iterate through the array and search for the id's you're interested in. Update
- Here you go: [IMDB JSON for specific ID](http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=1034314)

Comment: http://www.imdbapi.com/, use this ....

Comment: Did you mean to post your API key in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [IMDb-PHP-API](https://github.com/chrisjp/IMDb-PHP-API) you can get JSON data like this:

```
$movie = $imdb->find_by_id("tt0068646");
```

The "tt" part is optional.

*Disclosure: IMDb-PHP-API is a PHP script I wrote and is originally based on [this Ruby gem](https://github.com/maddox/imdb-party)*

Answer (score 3):

IMDB freely makes available most of their data through [up-to-date dump files](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces). I've written a script that converts these to fairly clean JSON:

https://github.com/oxplot/imdb2json

Answer (score 0):

You can also get full movie details using OMDB.
Here is link :

http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=YOUR IMDB ID&apikey=YOUR API KEY